# Why add column data to data frame not working with a function in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am curious that why the following code doesn't work for adding column data to a data frame.

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c(4:6)
df <- data.frame(a,b)  # create a data frame example

add <- function(df, vector){
    df[[3]] <- vector
}                     # create a function to add column data to a data frame

d <- c(7:9)           # a new vector to be added to the data frame
add(df,d)             # execute the function
```

If you run the code in R, the new vector doesn't add to the data frame and no error also.

Comment: You need to return `df` on the line following `df[[3]] <- vector` then assign `df <- add(df, d)`.  It's best to never modify objects in different environments from inside  a function.

Comment: Why does the df needs to be returned? And the function also doesn't modify the data frame object.

Comment: @Friday Interesting

Answer (score 1):

R passes parameters to functions by value - not by reference - that means inside the function you work on a copy of the data.frame `df` and when returning from the function the modified data.frame "dies" and the original data.frame outside the function is still unchanged.

This is why @RichScriven proposed to store the return value of your function in the data.frame `df` again.

Credits go to @RichScriven please...

PS: You should use `cbind` ("column bind") to extend your data.frame independently of how many columns already exist and ensure unique column names:

```
add <- function(df, vector){
    res <- cbind(df, vector)
    names(res) <- make.names(names(res), unique = T)
    res   # return value
}
```

PS2: You could use a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame` which is passed by reference (not by value).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!